# Please help me translate this sentence [明よせっないスキャットが]

Tags: translation, meaning, words, manga

I am reading a manga and I can't understand the sentence [明よせっないスキャットが]. 
So basically, here's the deal. Some people talking about the music. And one girl said:

> それに2曲目の金延幸子! よく知ってたわね～ 金延幸子! 大好きなのよね～
>   歌声が神秘的っていうか。圧倒的に「あなたから遠くへ」がスキなのよ。明よせっないスキャットが。

[image]

Comment: Did you copy that correctly?  The 明よ part does not make sense.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure. I added a picture for more correctly information.

Answer (score 5):

Alright, so it says 「明{あか}**る**せつない」 and not 「明**よ**せっない」.  The 「つ」 is the regular-size one.

「明**る**せつない」 is a substandard or highly colloquial way of saying 「明**るく**せつない」, which means "***sorrowful in a lighthearted way***".

「スキャット」 means "scat singing".  In this song, it refers to the all-katakana part:

「パパパル　パパプラルラ　パパパル　パパプルラ」

You can read the whole lyrics [here](https://www.uta-net.com/song/187532/).

That means nothing, mind you.  Scat singing is generally nonsense.

> 圧倒的に「あなたから遠{とお}くへ」がスキなのよ。明るせつないスキャットが。

therefore would mean:

> "(Among all of her songs,)「あなたから遠くへ」 is my favorite by a landslide. Just love the light and sorrowful scat part."

Comment: @Helena Thanks for introducing this cool song!

Comment: Thank you so much!